# How i can re-render Drawer in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing for the first time the login with Mysql and php in react native, and everything works correctly but the only problem i have is that the content of the Drawer is not updated until i restart the app. I'm implementing AsyncStorage to save if the user is logged or not, if he is logged then return the **My Profile** button and if it does not return the **Sign In** button. I have tried this: **props.navigation.state.params.refresh();** instead **props.navigation.navigate('home');** but does not work for me. Any suggestion? I'm doing something wrong?

**Login Function**

```
     const login = async() => {

     if (email, password) {

    signInApi(email, password).then(response => {
          
          if (response != 'error') {
          setLogged(true);
          props.navigation.navigate('home');

          }else if(response === 'error'){
          setLogged(false);
      }

    });

  }else{
          Alert.alert('Complete Form');
      }
  }
```

**DrawerContent**

```
export default function DrawerContent(props){

    const {navigation} = props;
    const [isLogged, setisLogged] = useState(null);

    const onChangeScreen = (screen) => {
        navigation.navigate(screen);
    };

    const checkLogged = async () => {
        const response = await getLogged();
        setisLogged(response);
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        checkLogged();

        }

    }, []);

    renderItem = () => {

        if (!isLogged || isLogged === 'false') {

            return (
                <Button onPress={() => onChangeScreen("signin")}>
                Sign In
                </Button>

                );
        }else{

            return (
                <Button onPress={() => onChangeScreen("profile")}>
                My Profile
                </Button>

                );
        }
    };

    return (
{this.renderItem()}
);
```

**Navigation Drawer**

```
import DrawerContent from './DrawerContent';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNav = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="app" drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="app" component={StackNavigation} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNav;
```

Comment: On your login function, I can see that you are have a state setter `setLogged`. On the `DrawerContent`, you have another state setter `setisLogged`. It appears there is not a single source of truth of whether the user is logged in or not. Ideally this state should be at a parent/ancestor component of both these components so that you can pass the true state of whether the user is logged in or not to the child components.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with parent/ancestor ?

Comment: Consider the following structure: `<ComponentB><ComponentC/></ComponentB>`. `ComponentB` is a parent of `ComponentC`